# verification code not working in php

Tags: php, validation

This is my inquiry registry page but for some reason the verification code in php is not working. please help. It is required for my school work.

```
<head>
<title>
Inquiry Form
</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<p>
<h1 style="color:blue; align:center;">
INQUIRY FORM
</h1>
</p>
<br>
<br>

        <?php
    $companynameErr = $emailErr = $phonenumberErr = $roadnameErr = $cityErr = $postcodeErr ="";
    $companyname = $email = $phonenumber = $roadname = $city = $postcode = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {

       if (empty($_POST["companyname"]))
         {$companynameErr = "Company name is required";}
       else
         {$companyname = test_input($_POST["companyname"]);
         }

       if (empty($_POST["email"]))
        {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
      else
        {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

        if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
          {
          $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
          }
        }

        if (empty($_POST["phonenumber"]))
         {$phonenumberErr = "Phone number is required";}
       else
         {$phonenumber = test_input($_POST["phonenumber"]);
         }

        if (empty($_POST["roadname"]))
         {$roadnameErr = "Road name is required";}
       else
         {$roadname = test_input($_POST["roadname"]);
         }

       if (empty($_POST["city"]))
         {$cityErr = "City is required";}
       else
         {$city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
         }
       if (empty($_POST["postcode"]))
         {$postcodeErr = "Postcode is required";}
       else
         {$postcode = test_input($_POST["postcode"]);
         }
    }

    function test_input($data)
    {
         $data = trim($data);
         $data = stripslashes($data);
         $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
         return $data;
    }
    ?>
<form name="form1" action="signup_ac.php" method="post">
<table border="1" style="width:30%; align: center;">
<tr>
<td style="width:50%; align:center;">
<h3>
Company name:
</h3>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="companyname" size=60>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $companynameErr;?></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:50%; align:center;">
<h3>
Telephone number:
</h3>
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="phonenumber" size=60>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $phonenumberErr;?></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:50%; align:center;">
<h3>
Email:
</h3>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="email" size=60>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:50%; align:center;">
<h3>
Road / Street name:
</h3>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="roadname" size=60>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $roadnameErr;?></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:50%; align:center;">
<h3>
City:
</h3>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="city" size=60>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $cityErr;?></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:50%; align:center;">
<h3>
Postcode:
</h3>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="postcode" size=60>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $postcodeErr;?></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align=center>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

My signup_ac.php contains (sorry about this but more detail was required and i didn't know what to write so please delete this bracket ladfhsdufbghisafg;hbsdchjnosdyhfsidufynhisdgfltbugisduafnhsldufgsidflgsidnfuhsdifusgdifudsgainfusgdafiusnfhnsdgfisudanfgilsdufghs;dufhnilsdkufhdikfungsisdjfylisaf.m,uhsl ):

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$tbl_name=temp_members_db;

$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand())); 

$companyname=$_POST['companyname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phonenumber=$_POST['phonenumber'];
$roadname=$_POST['roadname'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$postcode=$_POST['postcode'];

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(confirm_code, companyname, email, phonenumber, roadname, city, postcode)VALUES('$confirm_code', '$companyname', '$email', '$phonenumber', '$roadname', '$city', '$postcode')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){

$to=$email;


$subject="Your confirmation link here";


$header="from: SK Azmayeen Reshad <skazmayeen.reshad007@hotmail.com>";


$message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
$message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
$message.="http://localhost/myphpproject/Controlled/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";


$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
}


else {
echo "Not found your email in our database";
}


if($sentmail){
echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
}
else {
echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
}
?>
```

Comment: "_code in php is not working_" Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: the verification to check if the field has been entered is not taking place and it goes straight to the action. it just doesn't check the field.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and it worked fine for me.

In your form's `action` attribute you reference the file **signup_ac.php**:

```
form name="form1" action="signup_ac.php" method="post">
```

The validation code has to be in the file **signup_ac.php**. In your case I am assuming signup_ac.php is the file containing the code you posted above. Are you sure there are no typos or wrong names entered?

Without a better description I am not sure what else to suggest.